# Can an unused workflow argument be removed/deleted?

Tags: workflow

I have a TFS 2010 workflow template that I am currently working on that has multiple variables and arguments which are used for my build process, however, at some point whilst adding an argument, I accidentally clicked on the *Create Argument* cell in the Arguments table. This has created a new and unwanted argument1 that I cannot seem to remove from my workflow. I have tried deleting the name of the argument but this does not remove the argument, just brings up an error message saying that the argument cannot have an empty name. This is really annoying!

Is anyone aware of how to remove an unwanted argument from a workflow template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the Workflow Template in Solution Explorer and select "Open with...". Then select "XML (Text) Editor".

You are then presented with the xaml for this template.
Try removing the argument from here:

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" ...snip... >  
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="BuildSettings" Type="InArgument(mtbwa:BuildSettings)" />
    ...more...
    <x:Property Name="argument1" Type="InArgument(x:String)" /> <!--Delete this line-->
  </x:Members>
  ...rest of xaml...
</Activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution should be to mark the row with the argument and then press delete.